# How do I get the address of an element of an array which is an element of a struct which is a pointer

Tags: go, pointers, struct, slice

I have a recursive function which operates on a pointer to a tree-like struct.

The struct is of a directory, and one of the elements is an array of subdirectories (i.e. directory[]). When I'm iterating over that array, I want to take an element and pass its address (&) to the function. How do I do that?

I have a *directory, and I want the address of (*directory).subdirectories[7]. Apparently &directory.subdirectories[7] is not the address. What is the correct syntax?

```
type directory struct {
    name           string
    subdirectories []directory
}

func compareDirectories(asIs *directory, toBe *directory) {
    for k, inputDir := range toBe.subdirectories {
        for l, outputDir := range asIs.subdirectories {
            if inputDir.name == outputDir.name {
                compareDirectories(&(asIs.subdirectories[l]), &(toBe.subdirectories[k]))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the correct syntax for compareDirectories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&directory.subdirectories[7]` is the proper syntax, but don't confuse the type name with a variable name. `directory` is the type name, you need a variable of type `*directory`, and use that variable's name instead of `directory` (not necessarily a variable, but a value of type `*directory`).

See this example:

```
dir := &directory{
    name: "foo",
    subdirectories: []directory{
        7: directory{name: "bar"},
    },
}
p := &dir.subdirectories[7]
fmt.Printf("%T %+v", p, p)
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/B8sAWxGb_Jz)):

```
*main.directory &{name:bar subdirectories:[]}
```

Comment: Thanks but the issue is that it's a pointer to a directory, not an actual variable that I have. The code shown above doesn't compile because of "invalid indirect of asIs" and "invalid indirect of toBe"

Comment: @Villahousut The code in my answer and in your question compiles.

Comment: go run test.go for my code produces: "invalid indirect of asIs (type directory)". It doesn't compile for me. The issue is the line "compareDirectories(&(asIs.subdirectories[l]), &(toBe.subdirectories[k]))" @icza

Comment: @Villahousut Here's a playground example which includes your code, and it compiles on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/2Qq18XUYwJE What version of Go are you using?

Comment: Oh, right. Could that be because you're not running the compareDirectories function there?

Comment: @Villahousut No, if it compiles, it's syntactically correct. And if you add this to the end of `main()`: `compareDirectories(dir, dir)` it still compiles and runs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221838/discussion-between-icza-and-villahousut).